# $1 not working with sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression, xml

I have a bunch of files that contain XML tags like:

`<h>    PIDAT   <h> O`

I need to delete everything what comes after the first `<h>` in that line, so I can get this:

`<h>`

For that I'm using

`sed -i -e 's/(^<.*?>).+/$1/' *.conll`

But it seems that sed is not recognizing the `$1`. (As I understand, `$1` should delete everything what is not contained in the group). Is there a way I can achieve this? I'd really appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

PS: I tested those expressions on a regex app and they worked, but it is not working from the command line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`sed` backreferences have the form `\1`, `\2`, etc. `$1` is more Perl-like. Also, if using basic regular expressions (BRE), you need to escape the parentheses `(...)` forming a group, as well as `?` and `+`. Or you can use extended regular expressions with the `-E` option.

Note that sed regexes are greedy, so `<.*>` will match `<h>    PIDAT   <h>` in that line, instead of stopping at the first `>`. And `.*?` does not make sense (`.*` already can match nothing, so making it optional via `?` is unnecessary).

This might work:

```
sed -i -Ee 's/^(<[^>]*>).*/\1/' *.conll
```

`[^>]` matches everything except `>`, so `<[^>]*>` will match `<h>` but not `<h>    PIDAT   <h>`.

Comment: Another possibility is that the OP might be thinking that `.*?` is a non-greedy match.  Your solution, of course, has that covered.

Comment: @John1024 ah, yes, I forgot PCRE uses `*?` for non-greedy match. That makes sense now.

Comment: Impressive. Thank you for your explanation! I got an error with your line of code: "\1 not defined in the RE", but after a quick Google search, I realized it was because it didn't escape the `()`, but that was also given in your answer ;) Anyway, thanks again!!

Comment: @CarolinaCárdenas did you get that error when using the `-E` option?

Comment: @muru yes. Exactly.